# How to load all unique words of a specific file in an array and display them C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-handling

Stuck at point how to find a unique word in a file, all I've done is to load all the words and store in an array like below:

```
char *arr=new char[100];
char ch;
fstream my_file("name.txt");
if (!my_file) {
    cout << "No such file";
}
else {
    while(my_file.eof()==0){
        my_file.get(ch);
        arr[i]=ch;
        i++;
    }
  }
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
    cout<<arr[j];
   }
   my_file.close();
```

But now I'm confused about how to find unique words.
Any guidance.

Comment: You need a datastructure to hold the words you've already seen. Look into `std::map` or `std::set`.

Comment: Learn about [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Comment: Also: you did not "read all words". You read the first 100 bytes of the file. Properly reading all words would involve `std::string` and the `>>` operator.

Comment: For even greater simplicity also learn about [the `std::unordered_Set` constructor overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), and  [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). With these your code could be reduced to only two statements (plus a couple of more for the error handling) for reading the contents of the file, and another two statements for the printing of it.

Comment: so for the completion of this, I'll need to learn std::string, std::unordered Set and std::istream iterator ... it's a home assessment and they didn't  taught anything like that

Comment: At the very minimum you can get away with just std::string, std::vector, and `cin >> str`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude would write me a code similar to my question, which will help me to understand the functions better

Comment: Even without `std::unordered_set` this can be accomplished easily enough with a function that performs a manual search. This would be way too simple if sets/maps had actually been taught. It's not efficient, but it's what I imagine the expectation to be.

Comment: So, if you know the size of the array up front, why is it being allocated on the heap? The snippet, which is not an [mre], also fails to `delete []` the array, so there's the possibility of a completely unnecessary memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Your [unnecessarily] heap-allocated array is designed to hold 100 *characters*. You make it sound like it's supposed to hold many *strings*. There is a problem there in that your types don't really match. An array of characters *can* hold a single C-string. You either want an array of `std::string`, or a two-dimensional array of characters to hold many C-strings.

When you get homework, break the big task into smaller tasks. Break the smaller tasks into even smaller tasks. Keep going until you have a list of trivial steps. Do the trivial stuff, and eventually you have a program.

Your list of steps look like this to me:

1. open a file
2. read words from the file
3. determine if the word is unique or a duplicate

   - Add to an array of words if unique
   - Ignore if a duplicate
4. Print the array of unique words

You seem stuck on Steps 2 and 3. Step 2 is easily fixed by fixing your types. `std::vector<std::string>` is an ideal type at your level of learning. [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is **much** easier to work with than C-strings (null character terminated character arrays). [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is an array-like class that can change its size when needed.

The next problem-solving technique would be to start with what you know. If you feel good about the other steps, write them out. Give yourself a dummy file with like five words in it and make sure you can do everything except identify uniqueness.

Can you open the file, read all five words into an array, and then print the array? If yes, you're already 75% complete.

For the last task, let's open a new file and try to work this out independently from our [mostly] working submission. Hard code an array with five words, and put a duplicate in there. Can you create a new array of just the unique words? What would that look like? Maybe you automatically add the first word to the array, since it is automatically unique by virtue of being the first thing processed. Now, for the remainder of the hard-coded words, how do you tell if the word is unique? Maybe you need to compare it against every element in the unique word array. That's a loop and a comparison. If it compares to be unique, we'll add it to the array. If it compares as a duplicate, we do nothing.

Once that code is working, adapt it to fit into your submission. Writing the code is typically **not** the hardest part of getting a working program. It's thinking through the algorithm. I understand that at a beginner level, writing the code is also a challenge, but that's why you have homework. But even for a beginner, writing the code should never be as difficult as thinking through the process.

Now, the downside to beginner assignments is usually that the C++ Standard Library makes them trivial. Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) return 1;

  std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);
  if (!fin) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening " << argv[1] << '\n';
    return 2;
  }

  std::unordered_set<std::string> uniqueWords;
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fin),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::inserter(uniqueWords, uniqueWords.begin()));

  for (auto i : uniqueWords) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
}
```

This code "skips" a lot of the work you'll be doing manually. [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) is a data structure that can only contain unique values. Attempting to insert a duplicate fails. [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is able to take things directly from the file (using [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)) and insert them directly into the `std::unordered_set` (with the help of [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter)).

The printing is accomplished with a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Here's a sample run. Given the following file (you should have provided sample inputs and expected outputs):

```
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat bat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat mat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat pat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat vat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat
rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat rat cat
```

The output is:

```
❯ ./a.out name.txt
vat
pat
mat
bat
rat
cat
```

Which I know to be correct since I created the file.

Comment: Thanks, bro I appreciate your effort, This helps me understand a lot of things for like breaking a task into smaller tasks which is good.. and explained a lot to me as a beginner

Answer (score 0):

The [below](https://onlinegdb.com/5j4-2HxoPo) program shows how to count all the unique words in a given text file and then display how many times each of those words occurred:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
int main() {
    std::string line, word;
   //this map maps the std::string to their respective count
    std::map<std::string, int> wordCount;
    
    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    
    
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                //std::cout<<"word:"<<word<<std::endl;
            wordCount[word]++;
            }      
        }    
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    inFile.close();
    std::cout<<"Total unique words are: "<<wordCount.size()<<std::endl;
    for(std::pair<std::string, int> pairElement: wordCount)
    {
        std::cout << pairElement.first <<"-" << pairElement.second<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/5j4-2HxoPo).

Note that you **don't need** an array because `std::map` would suffice as shown above. The input.txt file can also be found at the link mentioned above.